# How do I prevent "svn update" to delete my local changes?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

My teamwork and I are using a repository for our project and the software TortoiseSVN to version-control it. We are 5 people working on it. And something happens very often when we do "svn update":

1) A partner and I are making changes on the same file (for example: "A")

2) My partner commits their changes, and so the changes of file "A".

3) I try to commit my changes, but as expected, it says "your files are out of date"

4) So I first do a "svn update"

5) Then I check my files, and then, some of my changes on file "A" are overwritten by the changes of my partner.

It should be marked as a conflict but it doesn't. And it happens every time we update, or at least very often. It's a really serious problem since it delays a lot the progress of our project.

What we expect is:

1) To update our Working Directory without our own changes deleting automatically

2) SVN should show conflicts when some of our teammates have committed changes on the same file we are working on, and allow US to decide what piece of code keep and what not.

What we are currently getting: Not all svn conflicts are detected but instead some of our local changes are deleted without advice.

Comment: On which type of files are you working?

Comment: @royalTS We are working on .js files and .ejs files, most of the .js files are just scripts with functions to manage the views of the application, some others are the configuration of the server, and others are part of the backend (que are using nodejs with express to make queries to the DB)

Comment: What you expect is the normal behavior of svn. Hard to debug without a way to reproduce it. What is the output of `svn status --show-updates` before a problematic update?